# Pointers Casting Endianness

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction, embedded, endianness

```
#include "stdio.h"

typedef struct CustomStruct
{
  short Element1[10];
}CustomStruct;

void F2(char* Y)
{
  *Y=0x00;
  Y++; 
  *Y=0x1F;    
}

void F1(CustomStruct* X)
{
  F2((char *)X);
  printf("s = %x\n", (*X).Element1[0]);
}

int main(void)
{
  CustomStruct s;
  F1(&s);

  return 0;
}
```

The above C code prints `0x1f00` when compiled and ran on my PC.

But when I flash it to an embedded target (uController) and debugging, I find that
`(*X).Element1[0] = 0x001f`.

1- Why the results are different on PC and on the embedded target?

2- What can I modify in this code so that it prints `0x001f` in the PC case,
without changing the core of code (by adding a compiler option or something maybe).

Answer (score 3):

`short`s are typically two bytes and 16 bits. When you say:

```
short s;
((char*)&s)[0] = 0x00;
((char*)&s)[1] = 0x1f;
```

This sets the first of those two bytes to `0x00` and the second of those two bytes to `0x1f`. The thing is that C++ doesn't specify what setting the first or second byte does to the value of the overall `short`, so different platforms can do different things. In particular, some platforms say that setting the first byte affects the 'most significant' bits of the `short`'s 16 bits and setting the second byte affects the 'least significant' bits of the `short`'s 16 bits. Other platforms say the opposite; That setting the first byte affect the least significant bits and setting the second byte affects the most significant bits. These two platform behaviors are referred to as big-endian and little-endian respectively.

---

The solution to getting consistent behavior independent of these differences is to not access the bytes of the `short` this way. Instead you should simply manipulate the value of the `short` using methods that the language *does* define, such as with bitwise and arithmetic operators.

```
short s;
s = (0x1f << 8) | (0x00 << 0); // set the most significant bits to 0x1f and the least significant bits to 0x00.
```

---

> The problem is that, for many reasons, I can only change the body of the function F2. I can not change its prototype. Is there a way to find the sizeof Y before it have been castled or something?

You cannot determine the original type and size using only the `char*`. You have to know the correct type and size through some other means. If `F2` is never called except with CustomStruct then you can simply cast the `char*` back to `CustomStruct` like this:

```
void F2(char* Y)
{
  CustomStruct *X = (CustomStruct*)Y;
  X->Element[0] = 0x1F00;
}
```

But remember, such casts are not safe in general; you should only cast a pointer back to what it was originally cast from.

Comment: Thank you so much.
The problem is that, for many reasons, I can only change the body of the function F2. I can not change its prototype.
Is there a way to find the sizeof Y before it have been castled or something?

Answer (score 2):

The portable way is to change the definition of `F2`:

```
void F2(short * p)
{
    *p = 0x1F;
}

void F1(CustomStruct* X)
{
    F2(&X.Element1[0]);
    printf("s = %x\n", (*X).Element1[0]);
}
```

When you reinterpret an object as an array of chars, you expose the *implementation details* of the representation, which is inherently non-portable and... implementation-dependent.

If you need to do I/O, i.e. interface with a fixed, specified, external wire format, use functions like [`htons` and `ntohs`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/htons) to convert and leave the platform specifics to your library.

Comment: Thank you so much.
The problem is that, for many reasons, I can only change the body of the function F2. I can not change its prototype.
Is there a way to find the sizeof Y before it have been castled or something?

Comment: If you know that you will always pass the address of a short to F2, you could cast its parameter to a short within the function body, and assign the value to that.  This will make it consistent with other uses of that memory in your program as a short, but potentially inconsistent with exchange of the bytewise raw data with another system which may be of different endianness.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the PC is little endian and the target is either big-endian, or has 16-bit char.

There isn't a great way to modify the C code on the PC, unless you replace your `char *` references with `short *` references, and perhaps use macros to abstract the differences between your microcontroller and your PC.

For example, you might make a macro `PACK_BYTES(hi, lo)` that packs two bytes into a short the same way, regardless of machine endian.  Your example becomes:

```
#include "stdio.h"

#define PACK_BYTES(hi,lo) (((short)((hi) & 0xFF)) << 8 | (0xFF & (lo)))

typedef struct CustomStruct
{
  short Element1[10];
}CustomStruct;

void F2(short* Y)
{
    *Y = PACK_BYTES(0x00, 0x1F);
}

void F1(CustomStruct* X)
{
  F2(&(X->Element1[0]));
  printf("s = %x\n", (*X).Element1[0]);
}

int main(void)
{
  CustomStruct s;
  F1(&s);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.
The problem is that, for many reasons, I can only change the body of the function F2. I can not change its prototype.
Is there a way to find the sizeof Y before it have been castled or something?